# Can QEMU be compiled with g++?

Tags: g++, qemu

[The wiki seems to indicate the default wiki for QEMU is gcc and the alternative is clang.](https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Linux).I am interested in utilizing c++ libraries in building QEMU directly. Is there a method to build QEMU with g++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of QEMU is C code and should therefore be built with a C compiler. A few small optional parts of it are C++, and are built with the C++ compiler -- ie g++ if using gcc, clang++ if using clang. configure will automatically find the C++ compiler and meson should automatically use it for source files with the right extension.

Comment: So if I wanted to add some additional functionality onto QEMU, there shouldn't be an issue in using C++? It should just work out of the box?

Comment: Technically speaking, yes. If you are hoping for these changes to go upstream, you should probably ask on the mailing list first, because C++ is currently optional and we probably would prefer not to add new stuff written in it.